# Who are the 'righteous' as defined in the meaning and historical context of Proverbs 18:10?

Tags: righteousness

### Proverbs 18:10 (NASB)

> The name of the LORD is a strong tower; The righteous runs into it and
>   is safe.

Who is considered "righteous" in this passage? All of Israel? Some of Israel/Judah? Those who call upon the name of the LORD? Is it a prescriptive or descriptive text? Can it be that those who run into it become righteous or can only the righteous run into it?

Comment: The audience of Proverbs, as well as most of Tanach, is generally believed to be a certain segment of Israelite society, q.v. [here](http://www.knowableword.com/2012/06/21/proverbs-audience/).  Therefore, it would seem that צַדִּיק refers to a righteous _Israelite_.

Answer (score 1):

In Genesis 18:17-19, we have God's thoughts as he was considering what he was about to do to Sodom and Gomorrah:

> And the LORD said, Shall I hide from Abraham that thing which I do; Seeing that Abraham shall surely become a great and mighty nation, and all the nations of the earth shall be blessed in him?
>   For I know him, that he will command his children and his household after him, and they shall keep the way of the LORD, to do justice and judgment; that the LORD may bring upon Abraham that which he hath spoken of him.

Here we have a solid foundation for a definition, from the very mouth of God.

**The righteous:**
  Those who both, keep the way of the LORD (to do justice and judgement), and command their children and households to do the same.

I believe the definition applies to anyone who reads the Bible for the purpose of seeking out what it means to be righteous.